# Quiero hacer una tabla que muestra contenido de una tabla con llaves foráneas, pero muestra solamente la id

Tags: php, mysqli, mysqlconnector

La verdad es que se me da muy mal explicar la situación, pero tengo una tabla centrada en un tabla con llaves foráneas que conectan con otras tablas, entonces lo que se muestra son números y no el contenido que deseo mostrar.

[image: Imagen del resultado]

Este es el archivo que muestra esa misma tabla

```php
<div class="tabla">
                <?php require_once('functions/connector.php');
                $sql="SELECT * FROM tb_tasques;";
                $result=mysqli_query($dbLink,$sql) or exit(mysqli_error($dbLink)); ?>

                <!-- Tabla de contingut -->
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <br>
                        <h1 class="titulo_formulario">Llistat de tasques</h1>
                        <br>
                        <th>Usuari</th><th>Activitat</th><th>Fase</th><th>Data inici</th><th>Data fi estimada</th><th>Data fi real</th><th>Hores estimades</th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php while($tasques=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $tasques["id_usuari"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $tasques["id_activitat"]; ?></td>           
                        <td><?php echo $tasques["id_fase"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $tasques["data_inici"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $tasques["data_fi_estimat"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $tasques["data_fi_real"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $tasques["hores_estimades"]; ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="enllaç_modificar" href="modificar_tasca.php?tasca=<?php echo $tasques["id_tasca"];?>">Modificar</a>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <a class="enllaç_editar" href="functions/eliminar_tasca.php?tasca=<?php echo $tasques["id_tasca"];?>">Eliminar</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php
                } 
                ?>
                </table>

                </div>
```

Lo que yo quiero conseguir es que se muestre el contenido que llevan esas llaves foráneas
[image: Este contenido]

No se si me explico, lo siento :(

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y como haces el select? porque declarar las claves es una validacion solamente al insertar datos, no tiene nada que ver a la hora de mostrar...

Comment: Para lograr eso tendrías que hacer uno o varios `JOIN` entre las tablas, y usar cada una para obtener los datos que necesites. La FK son precisamente para eso, cada dato reside en su tabla y los traes en los JOIN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que hacer uso de los [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)

```sql
SELECT * FROM tb_tasques tt INNER JOIN tb_fases tb ON tt.id_fase = tb.id_fase;
```

La respuesta de arriba te va a seleccionar TODAS las columnas de tb_basques y tb_fases, para obtener columnas específicas se las deberías de especificar o con queries más avanzados excluir

```sql
SELECT tt.col1 AS col_1, tt.col2, tb.col2 AS fases FROM tb_tasques tt INNER JOIN tb_fases tb ON tt.id_fase = tb.id_fase;
```

Answer (score 0):

Muy buena solución por tu parte, pero he logrado encontrar la forma de conectarlas usando "USING", desconocía su uso.

```php
<div class="tabla">
                <?php require_once('functions/connector.php');
                $sql="SELECT * FROM tb_tasques 
                INNER JOIN tb_usuaris USING (id_usuari)
                INNER JOIN tb_activitats USING (id_activitat)
                INNER JOIN tb_fases USING (id_fase) ;";


                $result=mysqli_query($dbLink,$sql) or exit(mysqli_error($dbLink)); ?>

                <!-- Tabla de contingut -->
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <br>
                        <h1 class="titulo_formulario">Llistat de tasques</h1>
                        <br>
                        <th>Usuari</th><th>Activitat</th><th>Fase</th><th>Data inici</th><th>Data fi estimada</th><th>Data fi real</th><th>Hores estimades</th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php while($tasques=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $tasques["usuari"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $tasques["activitat"]; ?></td>           
                        <td><?php echo $tasques["fase"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $tasques["data_inici"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $tasques["data_fi_estimat"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $tasques["data_fi_real"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $tasques["hores_estimades"]; ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="enllaç_modificar" href="modificar_tasca.php?tasca=<?php echo $tasques["id_tasca"];?>">Modificar</a>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <a class="enllaç_editar" href="functions/eliminar_tasca.php?tasca=<?php echo $tasques["id_tasca"];?>">Eliminar</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php
                } 
                ?>
                </table>

                </div>
```

Con esto incluyes otras tablas en la misma y solo tienes que cambiar el valor que se muestra por el que quieras en vez de escribir la clave foránea.

Llegando a tener este resultado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchísimas gracias a todos por la ayuda! <3

Comment: hacer select * es una muy mala idea. Estas trayendo absolutamente todos los campos de todas las tablas. eso implica mover un monton de datos por la red que no vas a usar. Especializa tu select a solo los campos que necesitas. Y tene en cuenta que using es una clausula que busca por nombres iguales en las dos columnas de las tablas. ç

Comment: Es cierto, pero en este caso estamos hablando de tablas con nombres únicos y con 2 columnas como mucho así que esta vez el USING es una opción valida.